# connecting to the vapor server running on Mac using iPhone

Tags: swift, localhost, vapor

I have a web app developed using server side swift vapor 3 running locally on my Mac. I want to access it using my iPhone on the same wifi as my Mac. How can I do that. I tried using `http://<the ip of my Mac on local network>:8080` but didn't work, even with firewall completely off. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Edit you `Run` scheme in Xcode and put `--hostname 0.0.0.0 --port 8080` into `Arguments Passed On Launch`

[image]

[image]

Then launch you server and try to reach it by `http://<the ip of your Mac on local network>:8080`

NOTE: `0.0.0.0` means that your server will listen on all network interfaces

Comment: On phone doesn't show up. I get these two in the console. [si_destination_compare] send failed: Invalid argument
 [si_destination_compare] send failed: Undefined error: 0

Comment: I tried again, it seems that the router was the problem and it worked. thanks.

Answer (score 19):

Add the keyword 'serve' for vapor 4.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Does it have to be over your local wifi? If not, I would suggest you to use services like https://ngrok.com/ It will expose Vapor port 8080 to the internet and you will be able to access it on your iPhone app, even over the LTE connection.

Simply run: `ngrok http 8080`. It will forward all of the traffic, for example:

```
Forwarding                    http://24ab019e.ngrok.io -> http://localhost:8080                                                                
Forwarding                    https://24ab019e.ngrok.io -> http://localhost:8080
```